# Pytorch - How to efficiently form this Transform tensor?

Tags: pytorch

I have a Set of Rotation Matrices Rs:

```
Rs.shape = [62x3x3]
```

And a Set of Translation Components Js:

```
Js.shape = [62x3]
```

I have been trying to find an efficient way to combine them into a [62x4x4] matrix which is 62 homogenous transform matrices. Currently I am doing it with a stupid for loop:

```
def make_A(R, t):
    R_homo = torch.cat([R, torch.zeros(1, 3).cuda()], dim = 0)
    t_homo = torch.cat([t.view(3,1), torch.ones(1, 1).cuda()], dim = 0)
    return torch.cat([R_homo, t_homo], dim=1)

transforms = self.NUM_JOINTS*[None]
for idj in range(0, self.NUM_JOINTS):
    transforms[idj] = make_A(Rs[idj, :], Js[idj,:])

FinalMatrix = torch.stack(transforms, dim=0)
```

This is highly inefficient, and takes almost 10ms to form. How can I tensorize this?

Comment: I got closer:

torch.cat([Rs, torch.unsqueeze(J_vec, -1)], dim = 2)

I just need to figure out how to add the [0,0,0,1]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps efficiency, but this should vectorize your code:

```
def make_A(Rs, Js):
    R_homo = torch.cat((Rs, torch.zeros(Rs.shape[0], 1, 3)), dim=1)
    t_homo = torch.cat((Js, torch.ones(Js.shape[0], 1)), dim=1)
    return torch.cat((R_homo, t_homo.unsqueeze(2)), dim=2)
```